# f-string reverting a rounded float to un-rounded

Tags: python, f-string

I have a function (containing numpy calculations, float32) which returns a dictionary, where the values are lists containing text and numbers.  Within the function certain numbers have been rounded to three decimal places as they are added to the dictionary.  Printing the returned dictionary gives an example entry (the four rounded values are in bold):

'51450049': ['ULT', 'IRU', 71254171, '30085', '11420', '20008', '23200', '22100', '46000', 'Z1', **10.132**, '---', 73566310, '50069', '10413', '20001', '23100', '22000', '46001', 'Z1', '---', **-51.269**, 71254171, '30085', '11420', '20008', '23200', '22100', '46000', 'Z2', **17.258**, '---', 73375014, '50063', '15833', '20001', '23100', '22000', '46001', 'Z2', '---', **-77.339**]

later in the code, values from the returned dictionary are written to a text file using f-strings.  Example code

```
file_object.write(f'{element_id:<13}{values[0]:<12}{values[1]:<9}{values[2]:<13}{values[3]:<9}'
                  f'{values[4]:<9}{values[5]:<12}{values[6]:<18}{values[7]:<9}{values[8]:<14}'
                  f'{values[9]:<8}{values[10]:18}{values[11]:15}\n'
                  )
```

where for instance, the {values[10]:18} command is referencing the value 10.132 in the entry above.  Similar commands are used to print the other three values on different lines in the output.

However, within the outputted text file the printed values seem to have reverted back to their pre-rounded state?  e.g

rounded values in dictionary:

- 10.132
  -51.269
  17.258
  -77.339

printed by f-string

- 10.131999969482422
  -51.26900100708008
  17.257999420166016
  -77.33899688720703

I know i can 'round' the f-string but why would i need to do this twice effectively?  I was rounding the number within the function to keep the size of the returned dictionary down, but am i missing something fundamental here? i.e is the whole float16 number retained? Thanks

Comment: You're asking to print numbers with 18 digits, so that's no surprise.

Comment: You are storing the "rounded" values as floats, which cannot exactly store the values you are referring to. The literal `10.132` does not produce the rational number `10132/1000`, so there's no unrounding, only a misunderstanding of what is actually stored in the `dict`.

Comment: If you care about this level of precision, use the `decimal` module to store your values, not the `float` type.

Comment: @chepner that's exactly what i suspected.  i.e. i was thinking that as i had added a rounded number to the dictionary then it would only literally contain, for example  '10.132'.

Comment: use decimals https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html

Comment: @chepner Then i could simply remove the rounding within the function and apply via f-string while writing out? Thanks, i'll check out 'decimal' module